# Can anybody explains to me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am having an issue building with dash plotly, the code is for a training planner and the callbacks are not returning anything under the training planner tab. I k now the second callback is the issue but how do I fix it? It is suppose to return to the HTML in app.Layout

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import datetime
import calendar
import random

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
def dropFunction(id):
 data1 = [
       'Preparative', 'Organizational', 'Maintenance', 'Thresold', 'Fitness',
       'Game', 'Recovery'
   ]
 return dcc.Dropdown(
                                   id={
               'type': 'dynamic-dropdown2',
               'index': id },
                                   options=[{
                                       "label": x,
                                       "value": x
                                   } for x in data1],
                                   #value=data1[0],
                                   placeholder="Select the activity",
                                   clearable=False,
                               )
def calendarGen(value, month):
 days = calendar.monthcalendar(2021, month)
 j = days
 days = pd.DataFrame(days)
 days.columns = [
       'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday',
       'Sunday'
   ]
 result=[]
 if value == 'Monday':
   c=0
 elif value=='Tuesday':
   c=1
 elif value=='Wednesday':
   c=2
 elif value=='Thursday':
   c=3
 elif value=='Friday':
   c=4
 elif value=='Saturday':
   c=5
 elif value=='Sunday':
   c=6
 for ind in days.index:
       i = j[ind][c]
       if days[value][ind] != 0:
           result.append(
               dbc.Card(
                   dbc.CardBody([
                       html.Div(
                           dbc.Button(children=days[value][ind],
                                      id={
                                          'type': 'dynamic-dropdown',
                                          'index': i
                                      },
                                      color="link")), dropFunction(i)#Passing the index for the dropdown
                   ])))
       else:
           result.append(dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody(html.Br())))
 return result
my_calendar = html.Div([
   dbc.Row(
       dbc.Col(
           dcc.Dropdown(
               id="month",
               options=[{
                   "label": x,
                   "value": x
               } for x in calendar.month_name],
               value=calendar.month_name[date.today().month],
               clearable=False,
           ))),
   html.Br(),
   #dbc.Row(html.P(id="dbc-button")),
])






app.layout = html.Div([
   dcc.Tabs(
       id='tabs-example',
       value='tab-1',
       children=[
           dcc.Tab(label='Session Reports', value='tab-1'),
           dcc.Tab(label='TSB', value='tab-2'),
           dcc.Tab(
               label='Training Planner',
               children=[
                   html.Div(my_calendar, id='monthChoice'),
                   dbc.Row([
                       dbc.Col(
                           [html.Div("Monday"),
                            html.Div(id='monday')]),
                       dbc.Col([html.Div("Tuesday"),
                            html.Div(id='tuesday')]),
                       dbc.Col([html.Div("Wednesday"),
                            html.Div(id='wednesday')]),
                       dbc.Col([html.Div("Thursday"),
                            html.Div(id='thursday')]),
                       dbc.Col([html.Div("Friday"),
                            html.Div(id='friday')]),
                       dbc.Col([html.Div("Saturday"),
                            html.Div(id='saturday')]),
                       dbc.Col([html.Div("Sunday"),
                            html.Div(id='sunday')])
                   ], no_gutters=True),
                   html.Hr(),
                   html.Div(table),
                   html.Hr(),
                  html.Div(id="Output"),#Where the output is suppose to go
               ]),
       ]),
   html.Div(id='tabs-example-content')
])


@app.callback([Output("monday", "children"),Output("tuesday", "children"), Output("wednesday", "children"), Output("thursday", "children"), Output("friday", "children"), Output("saturday", "children"), Output("sunday", "children") ], [Input("month", "value")])
def table(value):
   df = [
       "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
       "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
   ]
   print((value))
   for i, month in enumerate(df):
       if month == value:
           break
   i = i + 1
   monday = calendarGen("Monday", i)
   tuesday=calendarGen("Tuesday", i)
   wednesday=calendarGen("Wednesday", i)
   thursday=calendarGen("Thursday", i)
   friday=calendarGen("Friday", i)
   saturday=calendarGen("Saturday", i)
   sunday=calendarGen("Sunday", i)  
   return monday,tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
@app.callback(Output('Output', 'children'),
             [Input({'type': 'dynamic-dropdown2', 'index': MATCH}, 'value')]
            )#This callback is the issue 
def update_slider_example_min(input): #input  
       return input

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=random.randint(2000, 9000))
```

The part that is causing the issue is here:

```
@app.callback(Output('Output', 'children'),
              [Input({'type': 'dynamic-dropdown2', 'index': MATCH}, 'value')]
             )#This callback is the issue 
def update_slider_example_min(input): #input  
        return input
```

Because when taken out it is working pretty fine/

Comment: Are you able to strip away more code to get the [bare minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Would be helpful for anyone trying to answer.

Comment: @wxz Ok I did my best